# Low E string on guitar shows cannot be tuned to E2, why?

Tags: guitar, tuning

I just bought a used guitar and when I tune it all strings are good except for the low E string, which I seem to be unable to tune to E2, which it is supposed to be. What could be wrong?

Comment: How are you tuning it? What reference point do you use? What sort of guitar is it? What strings are on it? So many questions, the answers of which might help resolving the problem.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob, but it is a regular six-string acoustic guitar, and all strings are on it. What do you mean by reference point?

Comment: Reference point might be an electronic tuner, a piano, another guitar, tuning to itself.

Comment: Ah, I use an Android app called simply "Guitar Tuner", and it worked perfectly for my previous guitar.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Why are you unable to tune it? Does the app not display a frequency? Does the displayed frequency drift as you let the tone ring? Does the actual frequency drift? Can you adjust the tuning, but it goes out of tune immediately?

Comment: The app shows me the note I am playing, but I am unable to get it to E2. I can get it to E3 though. I did try to pluck the string softly and hard and in no way was I able to get it close to E2. When tightening it feels like I have to turn the knob for the E string a lot, even to the point where it might break.

Comment: So you get the A string (the second-lowest string) to the correct A2 value, and it has normal string tension, right? When you tune the E string such that your tuner shows E3, does it sound higher or lower than the A string? In particular, when you press the fifth fret of the E string, do you get the same A as the A string? If yes, your guitar is tuned correctly, but the tuning app is picking up the first overtone of the string. Don't worry, and start playing. If not, check that the E string is in fact thicker than the A string.

Comment: A lot of tuners and tuner apps have trouble on the low E string. It could be because the microphones have a hard time picking it up or the pitch sensing algorithm breaks down at lower notes - I'm not sure, but I've had this problem a lot with a lot of guitars and tuners.

Comment: If you have trouble tuning your guitar via smartphone with a microphone-based app, you might want to get one of those clip-on tuners that you clip onto your headstock. They cost <10 dollar/euro and measure the frequency via vibration. That way, you are less vulnerable to ambient noise.

Comment: Seems like it was the smartphone app (which I never had issues with before the new guitar) caused problems when tuning my new guitar for some reason. Depending on the distance from it, it would either register the open low E string as E3 or E2. Will be getting myself a proper tuner shortly.

Comment: tbh, it doesn't matter which octave it recognises, so long as it recognises the pitch itself - as it's almost impossible to be out of tune by that much. An octave under it would be like a slack rubber band & an octave over... well, you'd never get there in one piece.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a wild swing at this...

If you are using a meter & it can't quite grasp the pitch, there are a couple of things you can try.

- Pluck the string with the soft part of your finger *gently* - fewer bright overtones means more fundamental frequency for the meter to listen to. If you pull the string too hard it will pitch-bend - it will start over-pitch [sharp] & drop down to pitch over a couple of seconds.
- Rest your finger gently over the 12th fret & pluck as normal, which will create a perfect octave harmonic & tune to E3.
- Do it the old-fashioned way & compare the A string to the E on the 5th fret.

*From comments*
It doesn't matter which octave it recognises, so long as it recognises the pitch itself - as it's almost impossible to be out of tune by that much. An octave under it would be like a slack rubber band & an octave over... well, you'd never get there in one piece.

Answer (score 1):

The low E string of an acoustic guitar can generate multiple harmonics that are almost  as strong or occasionally even stronger than the pitch.  These harmonics are often easier for the microphone (and internal DSP filters and FFTs) of cheap tuners and tuning apps to pick up than the fundamental pitch frequency.  So you end up with a bad or misleading tuning indication.

Better strobe tuners (many available for iPhone and Android devices) won’t have this defect.

Comment: I develop iOS apps.  When testing my apps against many competing apps, I was surprised to find a huge fraction of the tuning apps available had this issue.